# Buffering in standard library in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have a question about the buffering in standard library for I/O:
I read "The Linux Programming Interface" chapter 13 about File I/O buffering, the author mentioned that standard library used I/O buffering for disk file and terminal.
My question is that does this I/O buffering also apply to FIFO, pipe, socket and network file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're using the `FILE *` based standard I/O library. The only odd thing that might happen is if the underlying system file descriptor returns non-zero for the `isatty` function. Then stdio might 'line buffer' both input and output. This means it tends to flush when it sees a `'\n'`.

I believe that it's required to line buffer `stdout` if file descriptor 1 returns non-zero for `isatty`.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Anything that's an ordinary file descriptor (such as those returned by `open(2)`, `pipe(2)`, `socket(2)`, and `accept(2)`) is not buffered—any data you read or write to it is input or output immediately via direct system calls.

Buffering only happens when you have `FILE*` objects, which you can get by `fopen(3)`'ing a regular disk file; the objects `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are also `FILE*` objects that are setup at program start.  Buffering is usually enabled on `FILE*` objects, but not always—it can be disabled with [`setbuf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf), and `stderr` is unbuffered by default.

If you want to create a buffered stream out of a regular file descriptor, you can do so with [`fdopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the answer, but I know that we can create a FILE object with existing fd by calling fdopen().

If we create a FILE object by invoking this function and calling fwrite() or fread(), will the standard I/O buffering be applied to pipe, socket, and FIFO?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what OP had in mind, but there is always buffering at *some* level, or it would be impossible to write a synchronous interface to pipes, sockets etc. while guaranteeing that no data will be lost.